# double point memory allocation

Tags: c, pointers

char **r;
    r = (char **)malloc(10);

the above allocation is enough?dont i need allocate for char *r through for loop?any can explain which one is right?

Comment: The above allocation is enough for _what_?  It's almost certainly not correct (unless you are on an unusual system with a two or five byte pointer...).  You might consult your C book.  If you don't have a C book, I'd recommend getting one; you can find a list of good books at [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 5):

This is most certainly wrong. A `char*` is of a size that doesn't divide 10 on most architectures.

Here's some example code:

```
char** r;
// Allocate an array of 10 char* in r
r = (char**)malloc(10 * sizeof(*r));
```

Now each element of `r` is an allocated `char*` and can be used to point somewhere.

Note also that in the above code I cast (as you did) the result of `malloc`. This is necessary only if this code is compiled with a C++ compiler, not a C compiler which doesn't need the cast. OTOH, in C++ you would need `new`, not `malloc`.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want to allocate 10 char pointers, this will not work. You are, instead, allocating memory for 10 bytes.

A char pointer is likely to be more than one byte. Hopefully, your compiler knows about the actual size of it.

```
char** r = (char**)malloc(sizeof (char*) * 10);
```

This allocates enough room for 10 char pointers. However, currently, they point nowhere useful. You need to allocate memory for them too:

```
int sizeOfMyStrings = 20;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    r[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeoOfMyStrings);
```

This gives you 10 char pointers, each pointing to 20 bytes of allocated memory.

(There is no `sizeof` involved here because it would be `sizeof(char)`, and `sizeof(char)` is defined to be 1.)

Comment: Small point: in C it's better not to cast the result of malloc (you have to do this in C++, but in C it's not needed and should be omitted so as not to mask otherwise helpful compiler warnings).

Comment: Better style would be char **r = malloc(sizeof(*r) * 10 );

Answer (score 0):

A char **r is a pointer to a char pointer. It can be seen as an array of strings. If you wanted to initialise all of the memory for the array, you would need to do

```
r = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS_OF_ARRAY);
for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS_OF_ARRAY; i++) {
    r[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * LENGTH_YOU_WANT_STRING);
}
```

or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to allocate memory for "2-dimensional" structure in a way that you want is:

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* for malloc() */

char **r;
/* we will allocate 'size' values, each of 'data_size' length */
size_t size = 10;
size_t data_size = 42;
size_t i;

/* allocate 'size' objects of the right type.
 *
 * Notes:
 *
 * 1. no casting the return value of malloc(),
 * 2. r = malloc(size * sizeof *r) is type-agnostic, so
      if you change the type of r, you don't need to remember
      to change the malloc() call */

r = malloc(size * sizeof *r);

/* Error check omitted for clarity.  In real code, always check for return
   value of malloc() */

for (i=0; i < size; ++i) {
    /* once again, no cast, and we use x = malloc(size * sizeof *x) idiom */
    r[i] = malloc(data_size * sizeof *r[i]);
}
```

The advantage of the above scheme is that it works with minimal effort for 3-, 4-, or higher dimensions, and is easier to read too.

In the above code, in the loop, I could have written `malloc(data_size)` instead of `malloc(data_size * sizeof *r[i])`, because `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1, but again, I prefer the above form because it's type-agnostic.